# Why my list is not displayed when hover

Tags: html, css, list, drop-down-menu

My list is not display when I hover over it. For the top navigation when I hover over English it should display more languages. http://jsfiddle.net/gTdsX

Comment: You really need to narrow down your example. Asking somebody to dig through your entire application and debug is not going to garner much help. Isolate the problem and post some actual code along with a simplified jsfiddle, and people will be more inclined to work with you.

Comment: Can you please send the exact code of that portion instead of entire page? It becomes really difficult to read all the HTML and CSS.

Comment: Oh ok thanks I'm going to do that now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add in your CSS to make the `ul` submenu be visible on `mouseover` of the menu item `li`.

```
#main-nav ul li:hover ul {
   display:block;
}
```

Comment: Haha, you were about 20 seconds faster. :)

Comment: @insertusernamehere Lol, that was very close indeed :)

Answer (score 2):

You didn't have a **:hover** style for your "main-nav". Simply add this:

```
#main-nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display:block;
}
```

… and it will work (tested it in your link).